# NavigationSplitView - last part not working - Why and what's the difference?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationsplitview

Still playing with the NavigationSplitView, but found no solution for the following.

I need/want to use here the `.navigationDestination(for: .....)` modifier and I want to call the different DetailViews with a switch but I can't get it to work.

What is wrong? Did I miss something here?

Data and Structs

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct Item1: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var place: String
    var date: Date
}

struct Item2: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var place: String
    var birthdate: Date
}

struct Item3: Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var city: String
    var dDay: Date
}

// Create some sample data
let items1 = [
    Item1(name: "Alice", place: "Wonderland", date: Date()),
    Item1(name: "Bob", place: "Bikini Bottom", date: Date()),
    Item1(name: "Charlie", place: "Chocolate Factory", date: Date()),
    Item1(name: "David", place: "Dungeon", date: Date()),
]

let items2 = [
    Item2(name: "Alice", place: "Wonderland", birthdate: Date()),
    Item2(name: "Bob", place: "Bikini Bottom", birthdate: Date()),
    Item2(name: "Charlie", place: "Chocolate Factory", birthdate: Date()),
    Item2(name: "David", place: "Dungeon", birthdate: Date()),
]

let items3 = [
    Item3(name: "Alice", city: "Wonderland", dDay: Date()),
    Item3(name: "Frank", city: "France", dDay: Date()),
    Item3(name: "Harry", city: "Hogwarts", dDay: Date()),
    Item3(name: "Iris", city: "Italy", dDay: Date()),
    Item3(name: "Jack", city: "Japan", dDay: Date())
]
```

Define the views for the detail area

```
struct DetailView1: View {
    var item: Item1
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text ("DetailView1")
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(item.place)
                .font(.title)
            Text(item.date, style: .date)
                .font(.title2)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView2: View {
    var item: Item2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text ("DetailView2")
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(item.place)
                .font(.title)
            Text(item.birthdate, style: .date)
                .font(.title2)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView3: View {
    var item: Item3
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text ("DetailView3")
            Text(item.name)
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Text(item.city)
                .font(.title)
            Text(item.dDay, style: .date)
                .font(.title2)
        }
    }
}
```

MyNavigationView description

```
struct MyNavigationView: View {

    let section1 = items1
    let section2 = items2
    let section3 = items3
    
    // Use a state variable to store the selected item
    @State var selectedItem: AnyView? // Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                    ForEach(section1) { item in
                        // Use the new NavigationLink with value and label
                        NavigationLink(value: item, label: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                    ForEach(section2) { item in
                        // Use the new NavigationLink with value and label
                        NavigationLink(value: item, label: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Section 3")) {
                    ForEach(section3) { item in
                        // Use the new NavigationLink with value and label
                        NavigationLink(value: item, label: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .navigationDestination(for: AnyView) { viewType in
               switch viewType {
                 case let viewType as DetailView1:
                    DetailView1($selectedItem)
                         .navigationTitle("Detail View1")
                 case let viewType as DetailView2:
                     DetailView2($selectedItem)
                         .navigationTitle("Detail View2")
                 case let viewType as DetailView3:
                     DetailView3($selectedItem)
                         .navigationTitle("Detail View3")
                 default:
                     EmptyView()
                         .navigationTitle("No Detail View")
                 }
             }
        } detail: {
            
                Text("Select an item ")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

How can I select the right DetailView to show up in the detail view?
When I use I get the error that AnyView is not Hashable. How can I solve this to understand what direction I should go?

Comment: What is `Text("selected \(selectedItem!.name)")` doing in the detail view? What do you want as the detail view exactly? `Text("selected \(selectedItem!.name)")` or `DetailView1`, `DetailView2`, `DetailView3`?

Comment: Was old Code, just removed. I want to see the DetailsView#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the list selection should not have type `AnyView`. The list selection should be some *data* that represents what is being selected, not a view. That said, you don't need this selection - since you are not driving the `NavigationSplitView` with a list, but with `navigationDestination`s.

Secondly, the types you pass to `navigationDestination(for:destination:)` should be the types of your *data*. It should be the same type as the values you passed to `NavigationLink(value:label:)`.

Since you have 3 types of items, you should apply this three times:

```
.navigationDestination(for: Item1.self) { item in
    DetailView1(item: item).navigationTitle("Detail View1")
}
.navigationDestination(for: Item2.self) { item in
    DetailView2(item: item).navigationTitle("Detail View2")
}
.navigationDestination(for: Item3.self) { item in
    DetailView3(item: item).navigationTitle("Detail View3")
}
```

Thirdly, the detail view of the split view is already determined by `navigationDestination`s above. You can't have a separate view in `detail:` when `selection != nil`. Just handle the case when `selection == nil`:

```
} detail: {
    Text("Select an item ")
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use a list selection type like this:

```
enum Item: Hashable {
    case one(Item1)
    case two(Item2)
    case three(Item3)
}
```

This is basically a way to have a single selection type for all 3 kinds of items. You would need to wrap the `ItemN`s into this type when creating the navigation links. Other than that, it's the same as a `List`-driven navigation split view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let section1 = items1
    let section2 = items2
    let section3 = items3
    
    @State var selection: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                    ForEach(section1) { item in
                        NavigationLink(value: Item.one(item), label: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                        
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                    ForEach(section2) { item in
                        NavigationLink(value: Item.two(item), label: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Section 3")) {
                    ForEach(section3) { item in
                        NavigationLink(value: Item.three(item), label: {
                            Text(item.name)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
        } detail: {
            switch selection {
            case .one(let item1):
                DetailView1(item: item1).navigationTitle("Detail View1")
            case .two(let item2):
                DetailView2(item: item2).navigationTitle("Detail View2")
            case .three(let item3):
                DetailView3(item: item3).navigationTitle("Detail View3")
            case nil:
                Text("Select an item ")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Aha, thank you, very clear. I saw once apon a time somewhere code wit a switch in the modifier. So I was stock in my mind with that. It makes it more logical and clear. I will test and come back.

Comment: Unfortunate it doesn't work correctly - the detail view is empty. Did append .onAppear( perform: {print("1")}) on each modifier DetailView# line, als in the DetailView# view itself but see nothing in the console. HOWEVER when I click twice on the item it works. What happened?

Comment: @iPadawan I cannot reproduce that on macOS 14.1.1 or iOS 17.0. Though on iOS the animations are a bit wonky, which can be fixed by just removing the list selection.

Comment: it is for macOS 13.6; can't upgrade yet. It is true that when the selection binding is not there it works. I noticed this to before in another test style. Is there a work around? Can I use somehow a different  selection type; maybe the compiler gets confussed?

Comment: @iPadawan Okay, there is the alternative of using an enum with associated values as a "sum type" for all three kinds of items, so that the list selection can be a single type. I guess navigation split views just had to be list-driven...

Comment: I love your latest change and is more the way I was intending to do it. Pity that you did remove your first solution. I think both solutions are welcome for the community. I din't see a notification that you did change your posting. Is that normal?

Comment: @iPadawan I removed the full code for the first solution because IMO the answer would be too long and it's hard to navigate the page. It's easy to figure out what to do from the other parts, anyway. And yes, not receiving a notification for editing an answer is normal. I didn't say I edited the answer in my previous comment, so sorry for that.

Comment: No need to sorry, luckily I got a copy of your original answer in use somewhere else.